# SAS: How to get a Pie Chart to display the MEAN of a specific column?

Tags: sas, average, mean, pie-chart

I have created a simple pie chart, but I want the pie chart to display the MEAN (average) of a specific column, which is the "PRICE" attribute from my dataset. My dataset has two attributes - PRODUCT and PRICE.

Below, shows my SAS code used to create the pie chart - but I need some help on how to get the pie chart to display the MEAN for my "PRICE" attribute.

Thanks - any help is much appreciated.

```
PROC TEMPLATE;
    
    DEFINE STATGRAPH MyPieChart;
    BEGINGRAPH;
    ENTRYTITLE 'AVERAGE PRICE OF PRODUCTS';
    LAYOUT REGION; 
    PIECHART CATEGORY=PRODUCTS RESPONSE=PRICE; // I THINK THE CODE NEEDS CHANGING HERE?
    
    
    ENDLAYOUT;
    ENDGRAPH;
    
END;
RUN;

PROC SGRENDER TEMPLATE=MyPieChart DATA=WORK.IMPORT;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add option `/ STAT=MEAN`.

Lots more info in the Graphics Template Language (GTL) `PIECHART` statement options [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=grstatgraph&docsetTarget=n156iuqrtmfqk5n1f8yye5xkgkir.htm&locale=en#p0bgn9gt4bp9t7n1ldllu5g9mw6a).

Example:

```
data have; input 
products $ price; datalines;
A 1
A 2 
A 3
B 11
B 12
B 13
C 5
C 7
C 8
C 10
;

ods html file = 'pie.html';

PROC TEMPLATE;
    
    DEFINE STATGRAPH MyPieChart;
    BEGINGRAPH;
    ENTRYTITLE 'AVERAGE PRICE OF PRODUCTS';
    LAYOUT REGION; 

    PIECHART 
      CATEGORY=PRODUCTS 
      RESPONSE=PRICE
      /
      STAT=MEAN
    ;
    ENDLAYOUT;
    ENDGRAPH;
    
END;
RUN;

PROC SGRENDER TEMPLATE=MyPieChart DATA=WORK.HAVE;
RUN;

ods html close;
```

[image]